# C++: proper way to pass Args && ... _args to nested list?

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, perfect-forwarding

Suppose I have a struct that holds a list:

```
struct etc {
    list<T> my_list;

}
```

Now, I would like to wrap the 'emplace' method of the list at the `etc` level to avoid the following problem:

```
etc.my_list.emplace(_Args&&..._args) <-- bad

etc.emplace(_Args&&..._args) <--- good
```

However, running into an issue: I can't figure out how to define my emplace method such that I am able to pass the arbitrary list of args to `my_list.emplace_front(...)`:  (psuedo-code)

```
struct etc {
    list<T> my_list;

    void emplace(what do I do here?){
        my_list.emplace_front(and how do I pass it here?);
    }
}
```

Comment: In addition to filling in the parameter list (which you knew, since you have a placeholder there), you will also need `template<typename Args...>` ahead of the return type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It has to be a template that accepts a parameter pack of types. Just like `std::list`'s emplace member is defined.

That parameter pack is used to specify `emplace` as accepting a bunch of forwarding references, which are then fed to `my_list.emplace`.

```
template<typename... Ts>
void emplace(Ts&&... ts){
    my_list.emplace(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...);
}
```

And that will do it. Template argument deduction will deduce the `Ts`, and the forwarding references, when coupled with `std::forward`, will make sure the value category of the arguments is passed onward.